# Webgl chrome blank canvas

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webgl, gpu

I am trying to render as much triangles as possible in webgl. Everything works pretty well with all webbrowser except with chrome. After 57000 triangles I get a blank canevas. So I check the chrome task manager and I saw that the GPU takes 2 700 000ko before this blank screen. Is it possible that the problem come from this ? Here the code : http://gogotriangl.orionhub.org:8000/triangles/ch04-05_BlueTriangles.html

Comment: You should post your working code somewhere online (selfhosted or as a JSFiddle) so we can take a good look at it. 57000 triangles is a trivial amount to render in Chrome WebGL.

Comment: Here is a link where I putted the code. Ctrl+U to see the code

Comment: http://gogotriangl.orionhub.org:8000/triangles/ch04-05_BlueTriangles.html

Comment: > Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating too many buffers. Get the [webGL inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/webgl-inspector/ogkcjmbhnfmlnielkjhedpcjomeaghda?hl=en), and running your app for a few seconds and I see you already created over 1.6k glBuffers:

[image]

But when you are drawing, you are only using the most recent:

[image]

Either re-use the glBuffers with `gl.BufferSubData` or delete the previous glBuffers via `gl.deleteBuffer`.